# Why use $subject in every Plugin Interceptor in Magento2?

Tags: magento, plugins, magento-2.3

How we define the plugin argument that need to as in the before,after and around plugin in magento2?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `$subject` is the original object or class you are writing a plugin for.